# GetCurrent user return only logged user from Firebase Google app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a login and registration app that does 2 steps

In one activity, he logs the user in, everything is correct, when I log in I can pull the user correctly to my NavHeader, however, when I need to register a new user, a big problem arises.

I do every method of registration and even see my user registered in the Firebase Console, however, when I try to pull this user with `user.getCurrentUser ();` it returns me the LAST LOGIN user in the app, ie the user who has just registered is not returned as current.

This method is response for update my nav bar with current user:

```java
    private void updateNavHeader() { // Funcao responsável por atualizar a navegação lateral de informações do usuario, tais como nome, foto e email
        // A funcao ainda não funciona corretamente, corrigir os métodos necessários para obtenção das informações
       NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView barNomeUser = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        TextView barEmailUser = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        TelaCadastroInicio telaCadastroInicio = new TelaCadastroInicio();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            if(user != null) {
                barNomeUser.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                barEmailUser.setText(user.getEmail());
            } else {
                barEmailUser.setText("Usuario nao logado");
            }

    }
```

This method register user in my app (first time)

```java
    private void cadastroUser(){ // Função responsável por coletar as informações dadas pelo usuario
        String emailUser1; // String interna para o email do usuario
        String passwordUser; // tring interna para a senha do usuario
        String nameUser = barNomeUser.getText().toString(); // Converte o nome do usuario para caixa de texto simples e atribui a String
        emailUser1 = barEmailUser.getText().toString(); // Converte o email pra caixa de texto idem
        passwordUser = barPasswordUser.getText().toString(); // Idem aos processos anteriores
        if(passwordUser == null || passwordUser.isEmpty() || emailUser1 == null || emailUser1.isEmpty() || nameUser == null || nameUser.isEmpty()){ // Verificação se os campos estiverem vazios
            Toast.makeText(this, "Campos não preenchido corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Erro exibido ao usuario no caso de não preencher os campos
        }
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailUser1, passwordUser) // Caso usuario preencha, criamos esse usuario no servirdor de autenticacao do Firebase
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() { // Se a criação no servidor do Firebase for um sucesso, prosseguimos com os métodos abaixo
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        Log.i("Sucesso!", task.getResult().getUser().getUid());
                        saveUserInFirebase(); //Salva o usuario no banco de dados
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { // Se o cadastro falhar, entramos em uma exceção no aplicativo e coletamos o erro
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("Erro interno", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

    }
```

This method is user for login in my app

```java
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) { // Caso não entre nos casos acima, tenta logar com o email e senha
// inserido pelo usuario nos campos, se o servirdor receber corretamente tudo abaixo daqui dá certo
                        Log.i("Login Completo", task.getResult().getUser().getUid()); // Notifica que deu certo
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TelaLoginInicio.this, MenuDeslizanteDaTela.class); //Muda para outra tela
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { //Se der qualquer erro no Login, como credenciais não conferirem com nenhum cadastro existente no nosso banco de dados.
                        Log.i("Erro no processo", e.getMessage()); //Avisa no log sobre o errro do processo
                        Toast.makeText(TelaLoginInicio.this, "Email ou senha incorreto, tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: The Uid from user is different of the user that i just registered, the Uuid that getcurrentuser returns is from a previously logged in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, the user registration method takes about 4 seconds (in my application) to get the user sent to the firebase server, and I called the activity (nav_header) right after the method call, so :

register user();
Intent inten = new Intent .... // And here I called the next intent, however, the registerUser () method wasn't done yet, so I added Intent to the new activity ONLY when task.isSuccessful was TRUE, that It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method which can give you all registered user from FirebaseAuth. One way to achieve is you can store user's email id in Firebase database while registering. And in case of new registration, just check if the email id exists in the database or not.

Comment: This is not my objetive, i want know the cause of my method createUser did not create user in Firebase.

Comment: REMEMBER:

Once you login using FirebaseAuth. Even if you close the app,the logged in user will still be logged in when you open the app again.You need to logout a user.